Keep cursor position on window focus (when clicked with a mouse)
When I do not have Visual Studio Code focused, and I focus it with a mouse by clicking on the text area, it will move the cursor to the spot clicked. With every other text edit application I have used, the first click simply gives that application focus without moving the cursor.
I could not find a setting to change this behaviour. Is there a way to change this? Usually, I would just want to quickly continue writing code where I left off when I refocus the application. I know I can use keyboard shortcuts, which I often do, but I also like to use the mouse from time to time.
